# implementing JS code into Angular app

Tags: angular

I've done a fair amount of angular tutorials and I feel pretty comfortable with components, services, forms..

Unfortunatly, I am not comfortable implementing JS and jQuery code into .ts files. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjgmz/1/

This code implements draggable, and it is straightforward in Jquery. How do you translate this JS code into a component?

This is what I tried.

```
export class TextComponent implements OnInit {

  box;
  drag = {
    elem: null,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    state: false
  };
  delta = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.box = $(this);
    $(this).mousedown(function (e) {
      console.log("down");
      if (!this.drag.state) {
        this.drag.elem = this;
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
        this.drag.x = e.pageX;
        this.drag.y = e.pageY;
        this.drag.state = true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
      console.log("move");
      if (this.drag.state) {
        this.drag.elem.style.backgroundColor = '#f0f';
        this.delta.x = e.pageX - this.drag.x;
        this.delta.y = e.pageY - this.drag.y;
        $('#log').text(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY + ' ' + this.delta.x + ' ' + this.delta.y);
        var cur_offset = $(this.drag.elem).offset();
        $(this.drag.elem).offset({
          left: (cur_offset.left + this.delta.x),
          top: (cur_offset.top + this.delta.y)
        });
        this.drag.x = e.pageX;
        this.drag.y = e.pageY;
      }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
      if (this.drag.state) {
        this.drag.elem.style.backgroundColor = '#808';
        this.drag.state = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. I am not sure if JS is even intended to be used in this way. The other option I could think of is to add (mousedown), (mousemove).. directives to elements an try to implement the functions in that way.

So actually, I am asking about practices of implementing JS into angular. Should JS be rewritten entirely? This sounds time consuming. Is there a neater way?

Comment: `this` is not correct, I think. I believe you want an element, but `this` is actually the component...I think.

Comment: I think you are thinking about this the wrong way.  You can't just take JQuery code and convert it to an Angular equivalent;  Angular and JQuery have completely different approaches to their methods, because **they were designed to solve entirely different problems**.  There are ways to *wrap* JQuery inside angular components, but expecting angular to do what JQuery does isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do it .
You need to tell Angular that you are using Jquery in you Component.

Eg - Using jssha lib in Angular

**Step One**

```
npm install jssha --save [using jssha for this demo]
```

**Step two**
Add the jssha scripts file in .angular-cli.json file

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jssha/src/sha.js" ]
```

**Step three** 
Adding a var in component to be used as a global variable

```
//using external js modules in Angular
declare var jsSHA: any;
shaObj:any;
hash:string; // the below code will go after ngAfterInit
this.shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
this.shaObj.update("This is a Test");
this.hash = this.shaObj.getHash("HEX")
```

**If the above dosent work out**

In your Case you need to put Some Template Reference in your Component and then Access the Element using View Child and then reference in ngAfterViewInit

Something like

```
<div #ref><div>

@ViewChild('ref') myref : ElementRef;

then use this myRef to apply the necessary Javascript
```